error: ‘regex_t’ does not name a type Ubuntu 24.04
As described here: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/4683 I'm experiencing, and it's not the first time during the compilation phase of a library, a strange error : error: ‘regex_t’ does not name a type :
raphy@raohy:~/googletest$ cmake --build builddir/
[ 12%] Building CXX object googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
In file included from /home/raphy/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-message.h:57,
                 from /home/raphy/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-assertion-result.h:46,
                 from /home/raphy/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:63,
                 from /home/raphy/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:38:
/home/raphy/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1042:3: error:   
‘regex_t’ does not name a type
 1042 |   regex_t full_regex_;     // For FullMatch().
      |   ^~~~~~~

Could it be something related and missing to my Ubuntu 24.04 ?
raphy@raohy:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2~24.04) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

raphy@raohy:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2~24.04) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

In compiling portaudio I get the same error:
raphy@raohy:~/portaudio$ cmake --build builddir/
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/   
pa_allocation.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_converters.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/   
pa_cpuload.c.o

[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_debugprint.c.o
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_dither.c.o

[ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_front.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_process.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/ 
pa_ringbuffer.c.o
[ 45%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_stream.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_trace.c.o
[ 55%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/hostapi/jack/
pa_jack.c.o


/home/raphy/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c: In function 
‘BuildDeviceList’:
/home/raphy/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:523:5: error: 
unknown type name ‘regex_t’; did you mean ‘gregset_t’?
  523 |     regex_t port_regex;
      |     ^~~~~~~

I compiled portaudio without any issues into another machine with Ubuntu 24.04 and version 14.2.0 of gcc and g++, where I searched for the file "regex.h", but, didn't find it.
Update 1)
I re-installed libc6-dev :
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt reinstall libc6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not     
upgraded.

git cloned portaudio :
raphy@raohy:~$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/
PortAudio/portaudio.git
Cloning into 'portaudio'...

configured :
raphy@raohy:~/portaudio$ ./configure
Configuration summary:

  Target ...................... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  C++ bindings ................ no
  Debug output ................ no

  ALSA ........................ yes
  ASIHPI ...................... no

  AudioIO ..................... no
  OSS ......................... yes
  JACK ........................ yes
  PulseAudio .................. yes
  Sndio ....................... yes

Builting, specifying the compilers version :
raphy@raohy:~/portaudio$ cmake -B builddir -
DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-14

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/portaudio/builddir

Compiled, but got the same error: 'regex-t' does not name a type :
raphy@raohy:~/portaudio$ cmake --build builddir
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/ 
pa_allocation.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/ 
pa_converters.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_cpuload.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_debugprint.c.o
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_dither.c.o
[ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_front.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_process.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_ringbuffer.c.o
[ 45%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_stream.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/
pa_trace.c.o
[ 55%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/hostapi/jack/  
pa_jack.c.o
/home/raphy/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c: In function    
‘BuildDeviceList’:

/home/raphy/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:523:5: error: 
unknown type name ‘regex_t’; did you mean ‘gregset_t’?
  523 |     regex_t port_regex;
      |     ^~~~~~~

Update 2)
Complete output of building and compilation steps of portaudio :
raphy@raohy:~$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio.git
Cloning into 'portaudio'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 7873, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (849/849), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (314/314), done.
remote: Total 7873 (delta 653), reused 632 (delta 524), pack-reused 7024 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (7873/7873), 5.76 MiB | 22.60 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4663/4663), done.

Configure :
raphy@raohy:~/portaudio$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... ./configure: line 10773: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for snd_pcm_open in -lasound... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for SNDIO... yes
checking for HPI_SubSysCreate in -lhpi... no
checking sys/audioio.h usability... no
checking sys/audioio.h presence... no
checking for sys/audioio.h... no
checking sys/soundcard.h usability... yes
checking sys/soundcard.h presence... yes
checking for sys/soundcard.h... yes
checking linux/soundcard.h usability... yes
checking linux/soundcard.h presence... yes
checking for linux/soundcard.h... yes
checking machine/soundcard.h usability... no
checking machine/soundcard.h presence... no
checking for machine/soundcard.h... no
checking for _oss_ioctl in -lossaudio... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for JACK... yes
checking for PULSE... yes
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for nanosleep... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating portaudio-2.0.pc
config.status: executing libtool commands

Configuration summary:

  Target ...................... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  C++ bindings ................ no
  Debug output ................ no

  ALSA ........................ yes
  ASIHPI ...................... no

  AudioIO ..................... no
  OSS ......................... yes
  JACK ........................ yes
  PulseAudio .................. yes
  Sndio ....................... yes

building :
raphy@raohy:~/portaudio$ cmake -B builddir
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Checking for module 'jack'
--   Found jack, version 0.126.0
-- Found Regex: POSIX regex.h   //  <----------------------------------------------------------------------------- !!!!
-- Found JACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a;Regex::regex
-- Found ALSA: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so (found version "1.2.11")
-- Found OSS: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
-- Looking for sys/audioio.h
-- Looking for sys/audioio.h - not found
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.8.1")
-- Found PulseAudio: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so (found suitable version "16.1.0", minimum required is "1.0.0")
-- Checking for module 'sndio'
--   Found sndio, version 1.9.0
-- Configuring done (0.5s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raphy/portaudio/builddir

compilation :
raphy@raohy:~/portaudio$ cmake --build builddir/
[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_allocation.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_converters.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_cpuload.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_debugprint.c.o
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_dither.c.o
[ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_front.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_process.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_ringbuffer.c.o
[ 45%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_stream.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/common/pa_trace.c.o
[ 55%] Building C object CMakeFiles/portaudio.dir/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c.o
/home/raphy/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c: In function ‘BuildDeviceList’:
/home/raphy/portaudio/src/hostapi/jack/pa_jack.c:523:5: error: unknown type name ‘regex_t’; did you mean ‘gregset_t’?
  523 |     regex_t port_regex;
      |     ^~~~~~~
      |     gregset_t

Update 3)
raphy@raohy:/usr/local/include$ ls -lah | grep regex.h 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root   85K ott 26 22:11 regex.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root   72K ott 26 22:11 uregex.h


raphy@raohy:/usr/local/include$ : | gcc-14 -xc -E -v -
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc-14
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2~24.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-14/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2,rust --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-14 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-14-ig5ci0/gcc-14-14.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-14-ig5ci0/gcc-14-14.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.2.0 (Ubuntu 14.2.0-4ubuntu2~24.04) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -dumpbase -
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/include-fixed/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/include-fixed"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 0 "<stdin>"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=./../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:./:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

Actually there is a bunch of regex.h in the paths #include :
raphy@raohy:~$ ls -lah /usr/local/include | grep regex.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root   85K ott 26 22:11 regex.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root   72K ott 26 22:11 uregex.h


raphy@raohy:~$ ls -lah /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14/include | grep regex


raphy@raohy:~$ ls -lah /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/include | grep regex
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  26K apr 15  2024 regex.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,4K apr 15  2024 regexp.h


raphy@raohy:~$ ls -lah /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep regex


raphy@raohy:~$ ls -lah  /usr/include | grep regex
-rw-r--r--   1 root  root   26K ago  8 16:47 regex.h
-rw-r--r--   1 root  root  1,4K ago  8 16:47 regexp.h

Which one should I keep, while remove the other ones?

It should be pulling in /usr/include/regex.h from the libc6-dev package afaik

@steeldriver I checked, and libc6-dev is already the newest version : libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.39-0ubuntu8.3)

OK sorry - can't reproduce. I did notice (in your linked bug report - missing from your question here) a mismatch between the gcc and g++ versions, not sure if that is deliberate?

Hi @steeldriver ! I posted above the output of gcc --version and g++ --version commands. Both gcc and g++ are 14.2.0 versions

So if /usr/include/regex.h is missing you should probably re-install libc6-dev (sudo apt reinstall libc6-dev). Note that what your interactive shell returns as gcc --version may not be what cmake sees - if in doubt, you can pass it manually ex. cmake -B builddir/ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-14

@steeldriver I'v reinstalled libc6-dev and built portaudio library specifying the version of gcc and g++. But still the issue persists. I've updated my post above with Update 1)

Your cmake output in the case of portaudio seems truncated - I would have expected more lines of output, in particular it should include something like -- Found Regex: POSIX regex.h. FWIW you shouldn't need to run ./configure if you're building using cmake - they are separate build systems. Are you using the repository's default cmake? what does cmake --version say?

@steeldriver I've updated my post above with Update 2) containing the complete ouput of configuration, building and compilation of portaudio.. In the building phase, where the C and CXX compilers detected are both GNU 14.2.0,  we read "Found Regex: POSIX regex.h". But, despite of that, in the compilation: error: unknown type name ‘regex_t

My guess is that you have another, incompatible, regex.h file somewhere earlier in the gcc-14 / g++-14 header search path (perhaps /usr/local/include/regex.h, but check the actual search order by running  : | gcc-14 -xc -E -v - and scrolling down to the section starting #include <...> search starts here: or otherwise)

@steeldriver Yes. There is a bunch of regex.h in the paths #include . I've put them all in the Update 3) of the post above. Which one should I keep, while remove the other ones?

Well I'm not familiar with /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/include (it's not part of of the Linux FHS AFAIK) however I'd suggest removing / renaming the ones in /usr/local/include in the first instance (or - at least temporarily - rename the whole /usr/local/include directory)

@steeldriver I've searched "regex.h" in the paths found with : |  gcc-14 xc -E -v - in the working Ubuntu 24.04 (the other machine). And in that working machine the only regex.h is in  /usr/include. So, I removed all the other "regex.h" in this machine, keeping it only in "/usr/include", and now the compilation of portaudio works fine. Thank you very much for your kind help. If you condense your hints into an answer, I will tag it as the solution.
